# run command lxrun failed

Tags: linux, windows

I use the command(cmd) "lxrun /uninstall /full /y" to uninstall my sublinux in my Windows 10.Then,I use the cmd "lxrun /install /y" to reinstall,but there is problem I encountered as flows:

`- Beta features -
This will install Ubuntu distributed by Canonical on Windows Under the terms of its license, see this link:
https://aka.ms/uowterms
Downloading from the Windows app store ...
Error: 0x80072f7d
Downloading from the Windows app store ...
Error: 0x80072f7d
Downloading from the Windows app store ...
Error: 0x80072f7d
Can not be downloaded from the Windows app store. Please check the network connection.`

I ensure that other applications include Windows App Stor can access the Internet,becase I tried and successed just now.
so,I have no idea and has anyone ever encountered this problem?